# Problems vertically aligning middle in fluid layout

Tags: html, css, mobile, fluid-layout

I'm having trouble with my first attempt at a mobile friendly design that works on all devices no matter the screen width.

[I set up a Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a94Lmjvm/4/) to show my problem

I am trying to get **header_avatar** to appear vertically middle of the header.

```
.header_avatar {
-webkit-border-radius: 50% 
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
height:50%;
margin: 21.5% 0 0 20.5% }
```

In the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a94Lmjvm/4/) you can see I have crudely simulated a half scale iPhone 5 and iPad Mini screen set up for example purposes.

The avatar in the iPhone example on the left is perfectly aligned, but as soon as I view it on my iPad (example on the right) the alignment is way off, not even close.

How would I make the avatar aligned equally on all devices, is it possible? The method I am using is completely wrong and I know why because the % is a entirely different distance on both devices but I don't know how else to go about achieving this.

Any help would ease my headache :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution, using :before and vertical-align:

http://jsfiddle.net/00adehLw/1/

CSS:

```
.header_left {
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    height:100%;
}
.header_left:before {
    content: "";
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.header_avatar {
    -webkit-border-radius: 50% -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height:50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Why does it work?

:before adds an element inside the element. That element takes all the height but is not visible since there is no width. Then, setting the vertical-align CSS property to that element and the image translate into a vertical-aligned image! Yay!

Comment: I'd usually rather use that solution than absolute positioning, so that the vertical-aligned element is not removed from the flow.

Comment: Both solutions worked in jsfiddle, but for some reason only @jlowcs yours worked in my full code. So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the top margin and position the avatar:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
margin: 0 0 0 21.5%
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/fgo3bq5f/).

The `top: 50%` positions it at half the container height, and the transform moves it back up by half its height.

Comment: Thanks @bobdye I wish I'd asked sooner now :) I don't want to get greedy here, but is there an equally as simple (or less so) way of making the left margin equal too?

Comment: The reason it is different is because you are using a percent left margin. In this particular case, you should be able to use a fixed margin, since it is never going to be more than the screen size, and that should make them all equal.